# How can I find out if a device has a vibrator?

Tags: android, hardware

I have a device of which I don't know if it has a vibrator.

Is there a way to query for the availability of the vibrator?

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but can't you just check the specs online if it's a specific device you are wondering about?

Comment: The question is meant to document a rather less known class. ;)

Comment: @Octavian: You might be interested in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68647/133368). It resulted in [this list of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`Vibrator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class does just that. It's [`hasVibrator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#hasVibrator%28%29) method returns a boolean indicating if vibrating is supported.

1. Get an instance of the Vibrator class which is a system service.
2. Query the Vibrator class using the `hasVibrator()` method.

```java
String vs = Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE;
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(vs);

boolean isVibrator = mVibrator.hasVibrator();
```

Comment: [Only since API level 11 (Android 3.0.x)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#hasVibrator(\)). How would you check this on devices < 11?

Comment: Are there even devices prior Honeycomb without a vibrator?

Comment: I don't know, and I'm pretty sure the app will be filtered from devices based on your manifest file anyway (uses permission android.permission.VIBRATE). But why was this added? Are devices starting on honeycomb and above not subject to the same filtering? Is it just something meant for the manufacturers?

Comment: It is a public API so it is definitely not only for manufacturers I guess. I have only noticed that there needs to be a way to query it since I'm playing around with my Honeycomb tablet which lacks the vibrator functionality. I'll kick off a discussion on the Android discussions mailing list.

Comment: You'd think that the manufacturers would know if their device had a vibrator anyway. I was just playing around with vibration functionality for one of my apps for the first time, and I noticed this. I don't understand why it's there, and thought I'd search around for an equivalent pre 11 method, and came across this question. Kick off a discussion! :)

Comment: I have such a device right here on my desk --- it runs Gingerbread and has no vibrator. Apps with android.permission.VIBRATE install fine.

Comment: If the device doesn't support vibrating, will the `Vibrator` returned from `getSystemService` be null?

Answer (score 9):

This may help for API<11:

`Context.getSystemService()` returns a service object or `null` if no service.

```
if ( getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) != null ) {
    //Vibrator exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to support (at least) Android 3.0 (11 HoneyComb) before you can use hasVibrator().

Oddly, you can use vibrate() itself on any/all versions.

So the REAL question is:  How do v1 - v10 detect if the device has vibrator?
(Or will nothing bad happen if you try to vibrate a device without a vibrator?)

Comment: _My_ real question is what I asked. If you have another, more specific question then just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll help someone.
Since I'm building a PWA, I ended up checking the screen size:

```
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    window.navigator.vibrate(300);
  }
```