# Making audio drivers available in R?

Tags: r, audio, driver

I'm trying to use the following sound package in R: http://playitbyr.r-forge.r-project.org/gettingstarted.html

After installing the package and its dependencies, when I try to run

```
sonify(iris, sonaes(time = Petal.Length, pitch = Petal.Width))
```

(per the example given on the page), I get this error:

```
Error in play.default(x, rate, ...) : no audio drivers are available
```

Anyone know what I should do? I googled around a bit, and it looks like maybe I need to call `set.audio.driver(name)`, but I'm not sure what to put as an argument.

(In case it matters, on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.)

Comment: AUDIO DRIVERS in R??? Oh my god... isn't there also Quake for R?

Comment: This looks a little new: the source only seems to have appeared on CRAN a few hours ago.

Comment: @TomasTelensky And why not?  Audio contains data, and can thus be analysed.

Comment: Well, but statistically, but why would you play sounds from R?

Comment: @TomasTelensky - QuakeR - is that a game where the entire community gets together to build a house in R? ;-)

Comment: @Tomas: Sounds can make for good "visualizations". For example, I love the NYTimes' auralization of the Olympics: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2010/02/26/sports/olympics/20100226-olysymphony.html

Comment: @John: Tis the gift to be simpleR

Comment: Well, can I watch films in R? Or does it have a device driver for a vibrator? :-) ( like in similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801574/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-device-has-a-vibrator )

Comment: @Tomas, scientists working the field of bioacoustics use sound through R all the time (e.g. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/index.html).

Comment: Hi Roman, yes I know, we'll use it too (thanks for the link!). But in my wildest dreams I would think about PLAYing sounds from R!

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu, you can get the portaudio headers with

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Then, reinstall the audio library. Make sure you see

```
checking portaudio.h usability... yes
checking portaudio.h presence... yes
```

During compilation of the audio package.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(audio)
audio.drivers()
play(sin((1:10000)/5),10000)
```

to see if you have audio drivers.  If you don't, or do not hear anything, perhaps `set.audio.driver(name)` or `load.audio.driver(path)` could help.

[This page](http://playitbyr.r-forge.r-project.org/help/getplayer.html) has some advice for Linux users, but says it works for Windows and OS X.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work -- I don't have any audio drivers currently set, and I'm not sure what I pass in to `set.audio.driver` and `load.audio.driver`. The page you linked to says `The audio package comes with several built-in audio drivers (currently "wmm": WindowsMultiMedia for MS Windows, "macosx": AudioUnits for Mac OS X and "portaudio": PortAudio for unix), but it also supports 3rd-party drivers to be loaded (e.g. from other packages).`, but `set.audio.driver("macosx")` doesn't work for me: I get a "driver 'macosx' not found" error.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you simply need to install the [Portaudio](http://portaudio.com/download.html) first. Download it, extract, and then follow [the installation instructions](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html). After that you need to reinstall the audio package (it needs to be recompiled to see new drivers) with simply typing `install.packages('audio')` again under R.