# How do I detect if an Android device has built-in haptic capacities?

Tags: android

I would like to have, in my application settings, the following choices for key feedback:

> None, Sound, Haptic

if, and only if, the device has **built-in** haptic capacities.
Otherwise, the options should be:

> None, Sound

How do I do this? By the way I'm **not** asking about whether the user has currently enabled or disabled haptic in his/her device, but whether his/her device has haptic capabilities.

I'm new to Android but I'm guessing that older/cheaper devices do not have haptic capabilities.

Note: My application targets Android with API level >= 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out if a device has a vibrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801574/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-device-has-a-vibrator)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
if (v != null && v.hasVibrator()) {
    // Add haptic feedback option
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know.This call unfortunately only works with API >= 11, and my app targets API >= 8. (I forgot to mention that in my original post).

Comment: I changed my answer's code. This should work better.